# Is it possible to use flutter for web and reactjs together?

Tags: reactjs, flutter, web, micro-frontend

I am joining a flutter codebase that has been built for web(no plans to migrate to mobile for now). My question is, since we don’t want to have to rewrite everything to reactjs, say I want maybe ‘examplewebapp.com/payment’ to be written solely in reactjs, is that possible? And how will you go around solving this problem?